# Declaring const of generic type

Tags: typescript

Attempting to reduce boilerplate, I'm declaring some sort of generic function interface as a type. Then I want to declare a `const` of such type. So, why typescript assumes that `foo` declaration is legit and `bar` is not? Aren't these declarations practically identical? Is typescript lacking simple feature or am I missing some details? Is there any workarounds, if I do not want explicitly repeat `FunctionType` interface?

```
type FunctionType<TValue> = (value: TValue) => void;

const foo = <TValue>(value: TValue): void => {
}

//const bar: FunctionType<TValue> = (value) => { // Cannot find name 'TValue'
//}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is a difference between a generic type that happens to be a function and a type that is a generic function.

What you defined there is a generic type that is a function. This means that we can assign this to consts that have the generic types specified:

```
type FunctionType<TValue> = (value: TValue) => void;
const bar: FunctionType<number> = (value) => { // value is number
}
```

To define a type that is a generic function we need to put the type parameter before the arguments list

```
type FunctionType = <TValue>(value: TValue) => void;
const bar: FunctionType = <TValue>(value) => { // generic function
}
```

Comment: @Hyster a variable can't be generic, so I am unsure what you are asking ...

Comment: Take a look at this example: `const genericFunction = createGenericFunction()` - the `createGenericFunction` returns a generic function (xD) and I would like to be able to write a type for the `genericFunction` constant and keep it's generic. Take a look at ma answer below.

Comment: Note that `<TValue>(value ...` in the above example needs to be `<TValue, >(value ...`, in the context of JSX in React (or elsewhere), in order to prevent the generic type specification from being seen as a tag.

Comment: The question was about consts with generic types. This answer is a subset of that because it is specific to functions. What if you want an object?

Answer (score 27):

I have been trying to solve the same problem, which occurs especially when I'm using higher order functions (or React components) returning other generic functions (or components). I've found following solution:

```
interface GenericFunctionType {
    <T>(x: T): string
}

const genericFunction: GenericFunctionType = (x) => `doSomething with X ${x}`
```