# Typescript generic function

Tags: typescript, function, generics

I'm missing something about generics in typescript. Suppose the following example:

```
type Caster<T> = (original: unknown) => T

const castA = <T>(original) => original as T
//                 ^^^ Parameter 'original' implicitly has an 'any' type.
const castB: Caster = <T>(original) => original as T
//            ^^^ Generic type 'Caster' requires 1 type argument(s).            
const castC: Caster<T> = (original) => original as T
//                 ^^^ Cannot find name 'T'.      ^^^
```

`castA`, `castB` and `castC` do the same thing: they cast a value to type `T` (ugly but fits the example).

The type `Caster<T>` describes the application `unknown -> T`. I assume I can create generic implementations of such function, however either `castA`, `castB` and `castC` give compilation errors (see comments).

The followings, instead, work very well:

```
// OK - but it's not generic
const castString: Caster<string> = (original: unknown) => original as string
// OK - but no reference to generic "Caster" type
const castGeneric = <T>(original: unknown) => original as T
```

It seems to me a bit obscure. How can I obtain this behavior? 
It would be very useful (think of factory methods)

Thanks

Comment: I think this answer might clear up some of the confusion around types that are generic functions and generic types that are functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197819/declaring-const-of-generic-type/51197906#51197906

Answer (score 0):

```
const castC: Caster<T> = (original) => original as T
```

expects Type like `string`

```
const castC: Caster<string> = (original) => original as string
```

---

when you call function you are actually using generics. So, `type Caster<T> = (original: unknown) => T` declares type with generics but `const castC: Caster<string> = (original) => original as string` uses it

---

```
const castGeneric: Caster<T> = <T>(original: unknown) => original as T
```

`Caster<T>`  is type declaration for `castGeneric` thus it needs actual type

Comment: That's the point! why this is legal: `const castGeneric = <T>(original: unknown) => original as T` but this one isn't: `const castGeneric: Caster<T> = <T>(original: unknown) => original as T`?

Answer (score 0):

`const castC:Caster<T> = ...`

You need to give a certain type to T
then the castC will turn to `(original: unknown) => T`

for example `const castD:Caster<string>` is same as `constD:(original: unknown)=>string`