# Extending TypeScript interfaces via plugins

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to improve the type definitions for react-table and have hit a stumbling block.  The library is extremely extensible, it provides hooks/plugins to extends pretty much any part of the library.  This is fantastic for the user, but pretty challenging when trying to author types.

For example, the main api returns a table instance object, that exposes columns, rows, cells etc.  Those objects in turn provide apis that you can use when rendering the table and those apis also provide access to various relevant parts of the hierarchy. The initial api is configured with a list of plugins that can extend the contents of any of these objects.

Currently I get around all of this using interfaces and declaration merging, it works, but because this requires global definitions, it makes it difficult to use several different table configurations.

The logical approach would be to extend the returned types based upon the plugins used.

**Problem 1**

This looked quite promising and I got code that worked nicely for extracting the relevant bits of an array of plugins.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never

type PluginConfig = {
  instance?: unknown
  cell?: unknown
}

type Plugins = PluginConfig[]

type ArrayPick<T extends Plugins, K extends keyof T[number]> = T[number][K]

type PluginEnhancements<P extends Plugins, K extends keyof P[number]> = UnionToIntersection<
  NonNullable<ArrayPick<P, K>>
>

type Plugin1<D extends object, P extends Plugins = []> = PluginConfig & {
  instance: { p1: string, rows: Array<Row<D,P>> }
}

type Plugin2<D extends object, P extends Plugins = []> = PluginConfig & {
  instance: { p2: string }
}

type Enhancements = PluginEnhancements<[Plugin1<Data>, Plugin2<Data>], 'instance'>
```

This gives a result of:

```
type Enhancements = {
    p1: string;
    rows: {
        cells: {
            column: ColumnInstance<Data, []>;
            row: ...;
        }[];
    }[];
    p2: string;
}
```

That's pretty good, but has a problem, since the `Row` type itself requires knowledge of the plugins in use, the definition becomes recursive with each plugin really needing the plugin list passed to `PluginEnhancements`.

I'm really not sure if there's a way to address this.

**Problem 2**

Ideally I'd like the types for the plugin list to be implied by the list of plugins objects passed into the various functions without needing to create separate types for each that would muddy the interface.

The library (in javascript) exposes plugins that look something like this:

```
export const usePagination: <D extends object, P extends Plugins>(hooks: Hooks<D, P>) => void
```

I naively thought that I'd be able to do something like this:

```
export type PluginHook<D extends object, P extends Plugins> = {
  (hooks: Hooks<D, P>): void
}

type usePagination<D extends object, P extends Plugins> =
  PluginConfig &
  PluginHook<D, P> & {
  instance: UsePaginationInstanceProps<D, P>
}

export const usePagination: usePagination // <-  doesn't work
```

But then I run into problems since you can't declare a const that's generic.  I did see [Declaring const of generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197819/declaring-const-of-generic-type), but the solution there, while it does work for the function declaration, then just moves the same issue down to the `instance` property.

I suspect that I've simply chosen the wrong approach for how to do this.  I thought that simply enhancing the existing plugins definition would be simple, but perhaps there's a better way to associate related configuration with a method.

Here's a typescript playground with both of these, along with some supporting types: [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=133&pc=8#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAVATzCzgF84AzKNOAciiwEMBjGWgbgChOsAPSWHBhESAUX6MMAEwA8eAHxwAvHDxw%20MHFIDOcYBgpYocAPJwA-IjgBtANJ6McANZYCECqYC6ALlN3PZHC%202ABuRtwA9BHqEtK6EABGAFZYrEIiugzMAK5Q2sBhADYEPPzQ8MLEcOJgklIASqm5%20UUEcooqahpa8cmpMJxwFqoxmnEOhsYmg0PDSHYOzq7uXr41dY05eQVYxTIm-oqkM0PBWGFQM7543JUkAKoYwJh4EACSuEba-c8YMvcdOAACnuox6cEkBGGQKcvnuAEplIoQhBgFIgnBQkZEd1xjDfPpJnA3oilMjUejLG8MVjLpw7nAAAqFbIAc30qAMwFZykQM302hgkmYWHMvmyGCcGAgAHcMDMRYVCmK4BKpbL5UNmBAWSAMCq1dK5Qqddk9R9BcLReLJUbNXBqDKDbaNZxjvSREyWeyMLoVMy2RzMBRudZPLdPQBBKBQRgERnAZhOORg8YBn3aAA0cHsuJ0SzcHjw1gwZoSRk8gOLpZA5agnn8Eaq6f0ogwAAsrSAcDBtDJGan8y3fdnc7wxvmXIWmSWyxXAY9fq8Ppo8j9MDIZgA5TBb7JKxgJQpYGTR2PxxPJxmj%20TyTh3zhRODln1ewMYNudjAi7u4GKMcBjw9ZtvX0ABGGQABFB16FJWGzAc810Yc-RsSteWHTkQx5AAyPkhgFIVvywXwkDAMDfEFKB9FZbNHW0XwzzjGR6llKDM0ZW8yDdJsSGHAAmKCYLgRI4JgBDhJQ3kw0BTDg25OA8IQflfSIkVSLgMB%20MomBqIwHljndBlPy7HtUPWaR%201Aj8O1M3A%202sYcIMgxghXkBDrMEly3M8bNaEIq1aEUB8ny0N8fRM4jf3gPgALAIDSgECpPWHAAJCAIGTaCkJEvp4KZSTrO0QFlKGIF2wypwGLgdLMr7SCEPkeFfBRNEeMS8p0iqWqqqEnLRP6CScpQkqZlZLAYGQXZCkZagwGqpi2iBRVCl8KalXYpl3IcS1iOuQ9jwtNSTwarbSUUAbWDvd0nyFI8SEu3s4AAWjgEAIEFYpVW%20Ch9yECA4G0CqZSEdsSFjGAweMLJmh2TFXNyB6PEhkgpFcxgHV2VzfiB4B5u4Pgkq6kh1sKPrx3BR6hoptMio6GZh0in8zP7PyVqCxT8NmbVdQwNbTXNVSrU2ziTgdWVfFYmURbvIZ3UJzqGSl8mJ1gwaCuGunlAZ6ymawaK%202vOhHQ5pSxZWhaY2Y0mZdl7iOsEBlUF5o7heymn8ypjWPeQrWlB1989YN1m6B5s0MFd4jTZmZ3w5lznStmWoGFwfmXaF4iZZmeWykdz1SdmiB5pVym8vE73VfCgV6aGPADqwSORXjs3ZjgMO9TT8PG5OxqxcdSW2NO0XW5WtbpqzuWCdz5KqljvUS-GL3EJ9qvfRr1eg5Zo3aHbjBTa5rUBd9RirbaOe-iH28xdJ-n0GwXBCGIGQC7m%20rGrtnOiYZOv7u7hfPbLtTSuI1tZDEZrZKKW8-IBSjooFu3Mj6W3PM-I%20f9L52yGPRE%20yDlboOzpEaIsVAIkHiu%20Xi30sCMkYD6bGG53aVyXoVd8xVQGrywgpHCAcfQ9WblzGB6k4D3G%20FQmhMBfjd0LsXS%207UFZ5yqEIyh1D9C0IjhnEUkj6rCUYZrZho0hi1HGtg5iuD37tSfG8KQTAlRQgUSI5RYjMCAwqvudE5Y26MAPPdOAhRgAuFBsAbQj5CHTzbpgQUFC7EYBUWAXw-81b5WXsAum5VKrVR6m-M6SI4CtSkFPIm2pVIRKUVEhxfMimiN%20FnIJb1GD6HULgKAJRZHwF%20t%20UpFCf7HjiblMSQDwQjSBDMAAdCM0hGYjFtDSpVW2nBmqqHrmg3u1TnorOqUQ%20KWBgIkG8hjFQSAondh0npAy3ACnhLGQKaS2RhHFJUeGTgZz4D8JICoa5WBOknXRtmO4KwLlr0GUMEZQy-mBPhKcsJ8BE4GKwJmE0vMswzHom6XkzyCGaWoSQIGEAXHPkxWgCa7YaLeN8SQSGATvDVMWixQeXzia-LpneJ8MooYkClk47FhRXEkWqUgC2Ezn7jx2d8kQ9LdFHGqXUFA01FgwFyI4LFOLywUqfLyo%20ndBa7SbpfOiEs4AmK2txUKMBmBDKAA)

I'd really appreciate any suggestions here, I'd hate to give this up as a lost cause when the only problem is my lack of knowledge.