# const functions, overloads and generics typescript

Tags: typescript

Typescript supports function overloading, which is pretty cool, and it's possible to make a constant function overloaded like this:

```
interface FetchOverload {
  (action: string, method: 'post' | 'get'): object;
  (action: string): object
}

const fetch: FetchOverload = (action: string, method: 'get' | 'post' = 'get'): object { ... }
```

But let's suppose I want to inform the **type of response expected**, instead of any `object`. I can do this by simply replacing `object` with the desired type:

```
interface FetchOverload {
  (action: string, method: 'post' | 'get'): UserResponse;
  (action: string): UserResponse
}

const fetch: FetchOverload = (action: string, method: 'get' | 'post' = 'get'): UserResponse { ... }
```

If I want to go even further and instead of saying it can only return a response of type `UserResponse`, I could return a generic type:

```
interface FetchOverload<T> {
  (action: string, method: 'post' | 'get'): T;
  (action: string): T
}

const fetch: FetchOverload<T> = (action: string, method: 'get' | 'post' = 'get'): T { ... }
```

The problem is that for `const` there is no a generic type `T`. And in fact there isn't, I need to declare somewhere that `T` is a generic type, but I don't know where!

I tried everywhere and couldn't make it understand that there is a type `T`:

```
<T> const fetch: ...
const <T> fetch: ...
const fetch <T>: ...
const fetch: <T> FetchOverload<T> = ...
const fetch: FetchOverload<T> = <T> (action: ...)
```

The only solution I found was to transform the `const` function into native functions with overload:

```
function fetch<T>(action: string, method: 'post' | 'get'): T;
function fetch<T>(action: string): T;
function fetch<T>(action: string, method: 'post' | 'get' = 'get'): T { ... }
```

So what I would like to know is if in fact I need to use it this way, or if there is still some solution to keep using `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "discovered" the answer as I ended up encountering a very similar problem in **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197819/declaring-const-of-generic-type)**, **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics)** and in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127985/755393)** and **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/755393)**. Basically I would just do:

```
interface FetchOverload {
  <T> (action: string, method: 'post' | 'get'): T;
  <T> (action: string): T
}

export const fetch: FetchOverload = <T,> (action: string, method: 'get' | 'post' = 'get'): T { ... }
```

Actually, the only weird thing is that comma after the type, but it's mandatory, so I don't have much to do. But it's all settled!

Comment: For anyone wondering why it's mandatory, the comma's so that the parser doesn't confuse `<T>` for a JSX element.

Comment: AFAIK, the comma is mandatory in the TS playground because for some reason it treats it as JSX/TSX. It should not be needed if it's only set up to parse TS code.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know what this type of interface declaration is called? Is there a special name, or is it just that typescript allows generic methods inside interface?

Comment: @smac89 this is called [**Call Signatures**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures). You can define it as a `type` or an `interface`.